# The expectation of the number of occurrences of the most frequent element in a random sequence

Tags: probability, asymptotics, expected-value, order-statistics, multinomial-distribution

We generate the sequence $\{a\}$ in the following way. $n$ is a given fixed integer, and for each position $i, a_i$ will be chosen from $\{1,2,...n\}$ with equal probability and the sequence ends after the first occurrence of the number $n$. Note that the length of the sequence isn't necessarily $n$, but we can figure out that the expected length of the sequence is $n$. What's the expected number of the maximum occurrence in such a sequence? Here the maximum occurrence means the number of occurrences of the most frequent number in the sequence. An asymptotic when $n$ tends to be infinity is also acceptable. Thanks a lot!

Additional Materials that may help:
The expectation of the length is $n$. And for such a sequence with length $n$, there exists some paper proving the answer is in $\Theta(\frac{logn}{loglogn})$ scale, but I'm not quite sure if the conclusion still holds under my assumption.

Here's the link to the paper: [https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/peer2peer/math/balls-into-bins.pdf](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Ecelio/peer2peer/math/balls-into-bins.pdf)

Comment: Do you mean that for each i, $a_i$ is uniformly chosen from {1,2,..,i} ?
Then each sequence ends at $a_1$.

Comment: I have just updated the statement. Here a_i is uniformly chosen from {1,2,...n} where n is a given integer.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the maximum occurrence in such a sequence".

Comment: Neither is clear what is "the maximum number of occurence in a sequence".

Comment: Sorry for unclear statements. The maximum number of occurrence means that the number of occurrences of the the number that is the most frequent in the sequence.

Comment: You could work out the answer for $n=2$ and for $n=3$ and see whether this gives you any idea for the general case.

Comment: Making any progress?

Comment: Lost interest, Marco?

Comment: The expectation of the length is $n$ and for such a sequence with length $n$, there exists some paper proving the answer is $O(logn/loglogn)$, but I'm not quite sure if the conclusion still holds under my assumption.

Comment: @Marco_L_T Then you should probably update the question with that information and a link to the paper. I was convinced it couldn't be as high as $O(\log n)$, so the result you just mentioned looks a lot more believable to me. Perhaps someone can make the paper's argument work for your particular case.

Comment: @user3733558 Thanks for your kind suggestion. I have already updated the statement.

Comment: Try to understand and model your problem: The length $L$ of the sequence follows a geometric distribution with mean $n$, support $\{1, 2, \ldots\}$, and the no of occurrence of $n$ is always $1$. The conditional joint distribution of the no of occurrences of $(1, 2, \ldots, n-1)$, denoted by $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{n-1})$, is a multinomial distribution, $\text{multinomial}(l-1; 1/(n-1), 1/(n-1), \ldots 1/(n-1))$, given $L = l$. So first we need to compute the expectation of the sample maximum of a multinomial vector, and then weighted by the geometric pmf.